# Qual a melhor abordagem atualmente para tratar as permissões do usuário no ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Atualmente estou trabalhando em um projeto com o aspnet-core e não tenho muita ideia de como proceder para tratar as permissões de usuário.
Eu até tenho uma ideia de como posso fazer (e já fiz), mas não sei se é a melhor abordagem possível.

Minha aplicação (Web Api) possui permissões atreladas a um usuário e quando o mesmo entra na aplicação ela deve passar a validar suas requisições a partir de suas permissões.

O que faço hoje é utilizar um [CustomAuthorizeAtribute] que realiza a validação das permissões através da rota da requisição.
Ex: O usuário solicitou `produto/get/1`, eu busco suas permissões do banco e verifico se ele possui a permissão para a entidade produto.

Alguma ideia de uma abordagem melhor ?

Comment: Não sei dizer no core como funcionaria, mas no webapi comum, eu trato com Claims junto com OAuth. Uma das claims que eu vinculo com o usuario no Bearer token retornado é a role do usuario, e em cada chamada eu verifico a role. Se não tiver a role pretendida, eu retorno uma exception.

Comment: Como tudo na programação, depende... hehehe
No asp.net core, eles criaram as policies https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies, sempre se baseando em claims. Segue um vídeo do cara que cuida dessa parte no asp.net https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pde_Hw2BsG8, se procurar por ele no channel 9 tera vários assuntos sobre ele. Security is hard. (: